# efficient way of finding a UserId in Facebook Friends List in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to determine if two Facebook users are friends.  I have the userId of both users, so I can get the list of friends of one of them using:

```
   $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

The documentation for the User object says that the id is a "string".  The problem is that when the friends list is returned, it's not ordered as a STRING, it's ordered as a NUMBER.  So for example, I'm seeing:

```
{"name":"AAAAA","id":"200000"},
{"name":"XXX YYY","id":"700000"},
{"name":"BBBB EEEE","id":"1200000"},
{"name":"OOOO GGGGG","id":"1200001"},
{"name":"PPPPP EEEEEE","id":"130000"},
{"name":"CCCCC CCCCCC","id":"100002999999999"},
...
```

If I want to find a userId in the list, if it were a "number", I could just convert the id into a number and do a binary search.

However, some userIds are very large, so I suspect they must be 64-bit ints.  And because I'm running on a 32-bit Linux system, PHP doesn't support 64-bit ints.

So, does this mean that the best way it to just iterate through this list in order, or is there possibly a more efficient way to find a userId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use **FQL**. It seems as if it would serve your needs:

```
SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND uid2 = ...
```

[**Facebook Documentation - FQL friend table**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/)

If you get a result, you know these two users are friends.